# Best Pattern to replace a util class

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

I have a `class` like `util`, It contains all preparing and calling requests (I want easily to manage requests). Ex:

```
public void reqLogin(String emailAddress, String password) {
    JsonRequestBody parameters = new JsonRequestBody();
    parameters.put(USER_NAME, emailAddress);
    parameters.put(PASSWORD, password);
    mService.login(parameters.createRequestBody());
}
public void reqRegister(LocationWrapper location) {
    JsonRequestBody jsonRequestBody = new JsonRequestBody();
    jsonRequestBody.put(DEVICE_TOKEN, "myToken");
    jsonRequestBody.put(DEVICE_TOKEN_TYPE, "type");
    mService.register(jsonRequestBody.createRequestBody());
}

...
```

But problem of this design is that in `LoginFragment` I can call `Register request`, and in `RegisterFragment` I can call `Login request`. So, is it bad solution to create this `util` class? Is there a pattern to solve my `issue`?

Answer (score 2):

> So, is it bad solution to create this util class?

`Util` classes don't delegate the processing to other classes. They work on the inputs, do some calculation and return result. In your example, you are delegating tasks to service classes from util. That's just not right. Instead service classes should call to util methods.

And, Utils shouldn't have business logic. Look at [Math](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) class.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is cleared to me. However, suppose the class is not a `util` like @Lebedevsd said, can you suggest me how I solve my problem, I want to group all requests in 1 class.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid `GodObject` antipattern after you would have 60 API calls, for example, you can use something like `Command` design pattern.

```
interface APIOperation {
    void execute();
}

class LoginAPIOperation implements APIOperation {
    private final String mEmail, mPass;

    public LoginAPIOperation(String emailAddress, String password) {
        mEmail = emailAddress;
        mPass = password;
    }

    public void execute() {
        JsonRequestBody parameters = new JsonRequestBody();
        parameters.put(USER_NAME, mEmail);
        parameters.put(PASSWORD, mPass);
        mService.login(parameters.createRequestBody());
    }
}

new LoginAPIOperation("user@gmail.com","qwerty").execute();
```

You can reuse this in different classes.

Answer (score 0):

one of the solutions could be 2 different interfaces for your class:

```
class RequestManager implemets LoginRequest, RegistrationRequest{
    @Override //method from LoginRequest
    public void reqLogin(String emailAddress, String password) {
       JsonRequestBody parameters = new JsonRequestBody();
       parameters.put(USER_NAME, emailAddress);
       parameters.put(PASSWORD, password);
       mService.login(parameters.createRequestBody());
    }
    @Override //method from RegistrationRequest
    public void reqRegister(LocationWrapper location) {
       JsonRequestBody jsonRequestBody = new JsonRequestBody();
       jsonRequestBody.put(DEVICE_TOKEN, "myToken");
       jsonRequestBody.put(DEVICE_TOKEN_TYPE, "type");
       mService.register(jsonRequestBody.createRequestBody());
    }
}
```

other solution could be just 2 separate classes doing Login and Registration.

As mentioned above this class is not Utils class, it is more like network processor or request manager.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it's not good if many interfaces are used

Comment: @JohnSteve could you explain why it is not good for you? inside of different classes your object acts only like an exact instance of the interface, which you have assign. I think it is the best option to keep all the functionality about requests in one class, but show only part of it, to the client through the interface.

Comment: @JohnSteve other option will be to create subclasses of RequestManager, and ask for them: RequestManager.provideLoginRequestManager(), which will be inner class (so all the context of RequestManager will be visible for it, but again masked by other class)

Comment: Suppose I have 30 interfaces, as your implementation, the `RequestManager` have to implements too much `interfaces`. Thanks !